# SQLite Database disappears after starting debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

I am writing a C# WPF application in visual studio 2015 creating sqlite databases with System.Data.SQLite.

This is an extract of the part that creates the database (there are other places it is used.

```
connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", _databaseFile));
connection.Open();
string sql = "create table Battery(date INTEGER, level INTEGER)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

... create some more tables

connection.Close();
```

I run my application up in the debugger, and it creates the database and writes data to it. After quitting I can open that database, view the contents and it contains the data as expected.

If I then start the application in the debugger again, my database is deleted (and then made new as it is created if it is missing). However, it is deleted without any input from me. It is deleted before any of my code is executed, and long before the database code which kicks in after a few seconds of connecting to comms ports. I have put a breakpoint at OnStartup in App,xaml.cs, it is there when I select debug and it is gone when it hits the breakpoint. I have tried selecting 'step into' rather than running, and it goes at that point as well.

If I make a duplicate of the database before I start, and after it deletes the database, quit and copy it in place, the next time round it will again delete that database even though at this point it hasn't ever opened it.

If I run the application (so it creates the database), quit the application, quit visual studio 2015, restart visual studio 2015 and run the application again, this time it doesn't delete the database, and all is fine and it uses it without issues.

I would like to know what causes the database to be deleted, in case this causes me trouble later.

Obviously I have a workaround by quitting VS2015 after the database is made, and if I just add to an existing database I don't get this issue, but it makes me worry that somehow VS2015 has some connection to the database that might cause me issues later.